# get id from url (or kwargs) for django class-based form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use a basic form to add data into my app, but I've setup a structure to seperate everything into 'projects'.

Everything is filtered by the project you select, and a project has a manytomanykey to a user.

my urls are then setup to be:

**//backend/projects

**//backend/projects[projid]/capabilities

Then when I add a 'capability' element, I need to read the 'project' id from the URL or kwargs

how do I access the capability_project (when rendering the form template)

i.e. the submit button redirecting the user back to the right project page

```
<form id="capability-form" method="post" action="backend/projects/{{ project_capability }} /capabilities">
```

I think because its a many to many it returns an iterator error. How should I be doing this? and how should I make sure the project_id value is always correctly when adding items?
// edit to update `NoReverseMatch` error im getting from aparently not being able to access kwargs of the form.

```
NoReverseMatch at /backend/projects/1/capabilities/add/
Reverse for 'capability-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://c9589d:8000/backend/projects/1/capabilities/add/
```

and further trace info

```
Request information

GET No GET data
POST Variable   Value
status  u'12'
domain  u'2'
capability_num  u'1'
level   u'a'
description u'asasd'
submit  u'Create Capability'
project u'1'
csrfmiddlewaretoken u'RW2vMwu3BhCOOhDTRaSeCglDSBCctqeF'
name    u'asdsd'
```

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    proj_name = models.CharField()
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='assigned_to')

class Capability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    current_status = models.BooleanField()
    future_status = models.NullBooleanField()

class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    capability = models.ForeignKey(Capability)
    current_status = models.BooleanField()
    future_status = models.NullBooleanField()
```

views.py

```
class Add_Capability(CreateView):
    template_name = 'backend/add_capability.html'
    model = Capability
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'status', 'capability_num', 'project', 'domain']
    form_class = CapabilityForm
```

forms.py

```
class CapabilityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Please enter a name for the capability")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Please enter a description for the capability")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Approved")
    capability_num = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=4, help_text="Enter a number")
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project, null=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LEVELS_CHOICES, default="Approved")
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(Domain)

    class Meta:
        model = Capability
        fields = ('name', 'description',)
```

urls.py

```
# /backend/1/capabilities
url(r'^projects/(?P<capability_project>\d+)/capabilities/$', views.CapabilityList.as_view(), name='capability-list'),

# /backend/capabilities/add - Add capabilities
url(r'^projects/(?P<capability_project>\d+)/capabilities/add/$', views.Add_Capability.as_view(), name='add-capability'),

# /backend/projects
url(r'^projects/$', views.ProjectList.as_view(), name='projects'),
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to specify anything in the form action. It needs to post back to the same AddView, otherwise it won't be processed.

Comment: paste the error traceback you're getting

Comment: does `Add_Capability` view have `form_class = CapabilityForm` in its definition?

Comment: ill add the error im getting when i get back home tonight, but I want to redirect to 'projects/1/capabilities page (depending on proj id) after a successful postback. @Anentropic, ive shown the whole form class above, does it need a form_class definition?

Comment: OK, but that should be done in the `get_redirect_url` method of the view, not in the form action.

Comment: @heymishy how does the view know to use your custom form class otherwise? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin

Comment: @entropic apologies I did have it i just temporarily commented it out and forgot to include in this question. What I am failing to see is how to include / pass the project_I'd back so that get_redirect_url can evaluate the url as defined in urls.py which expects the <capability_project> passed in

Comment: @entropic or @anush any ideas? When I try to use the kwargs like `kwargs={'project': self.project}` I get an error or a manytomany manager error. I thought it should be just the value of the selected project from the form post?

Answer (score -2):

In the views.py you can access kwargs this way:

```
class Add_Capability(CreateView):
    template_name = 'backend/add_capability.html'
    model = Capability
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'status', 'capability_num', 'project', 'domain']
    form_class = CapabilityForm
    project_id = False

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.success_url = reverse('project-detail')+self.kwargs['capability_project']+'/'
        return super(Add_Capability, self).get_success_url()
```

Comment: arent you supposed to use something like   `def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs={'capability_project': self.capability_project})`

Comment: I get the following: `mproperlyConfigured at /backend/projects/1/capabilities/add/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
Request Method: POST`

Comment: @heymishy i have edited the code. I have added a get_success_url function.

Comment: thank you, its almost there, it except it doesnt seem to be accssing the value of the kwargs properly. I have edited my above post with the additional info